# Start and Stop Recording Live Stream with button in Python VLC

Tags: python, python-3.x, vlc, libvlc

I have a script that plays live streaming from RTSP protocol in python using VLC library.

I want a button to start recording the stream on button click. From the documentations I get that only way to save stream is using

```
--sout file/muxer:stream.xyz
```

The document says I need to use sout while initiating the vlc instance like this.

```
i = vlc.Instance(url_to_video_feed, "--sout=file/ps:output.mpg")
```

This would mean the entire streaming video feed will be saved in the output.mpg file. I only want certain sections of the video feed to save.

Below is the snippet of how the script to stream the video

```
    self.Instance = vlc.Instance()
    self.player = self.Instance .media_player_new()


    media = self.Instance .media_new(url_to_video_feed,':network-caching=300', )
    self.player.set_media(media)
    self.player.play() # hit the player button
```

Comment: Use **allways** `--sout`, but writing to `stdout` and `pipe` back to your script. You have to process the piped stream in a `thread`.